# Calculate the square root of a number in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{7})$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, systems-of-equations, extension-field

How can I calculate the root of a number in extension field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{7})=\{\alpha + \beta\sqrt[3]{7} + \gamma\sqrt[3]{7^2} | \alpha,\beta,\gamma \in  \mathbb{Q}\}$?

Any number in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{7})$ is a vector with the elements $\alpha \beta \gamma$.

So multiplication of a number with itself results in
$(\alpha^2 + 14\beta\gamma) + (7\gamma^2 + 2\alpha\beta)\sqrt[3]{7} + (\beta^2 + 2\alpha\gamma)\sqrt[3]{7^2}$.

Reversing this would mean solving the system of equations above for the vector to be square rooted. But how?

Comment: Do you know the class number of this field, and do you have in hand a primitive unit?

Comment: Yes indeed square root. I edited the subject so it now mentions square root.

Comment: The class snumber is 1

Comment: To find a square root (in $\mathbb{Q}$) of $8281/152881$, is there another way than decomposing into prime factors ? Since the class number is one, the same trick should work.

Comment: Are you quite sure that the class number is $1$? If so, please tell me what an element of norm $3$ is, that is a $z\in\Bbb Z[\sqrt[3]7\,]$ such that $z^3=3u$ for a unit $u$.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Produce a cubic equation for the square root. This can be done by factoring polynomial with rational coefficients. Once we have the equation, it is easy to find the element (thanks for @Lubin: for providing the explicit form  of the cubic equation -- makes the last step straightforward)

An element $\alpha + \beta \sqrt[3]{7} + \gamma \sqrt[3]{7^2}$ in $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[3]{7}]$ is a root of a polynomial with rational coefficients. 
$$P(x)=\prod_{\omega^{3}=1}( x- (\alpha + \beta \sqrt[3]{7}\omega + \gamma \sqrt[3]{7^2}\omega^2))=\\=x^3−3\alpha x^2 +(3\alpha^2 −21\beta \gamma)X−(\alpha^3+7 \beta^3 +49 \gamma^3− 21\alpha \beta \gamma)$$ Its square root $\sqrt{\alpha + \beta \sqrt[3]{7} + \gamma \sqrt[3]{7^2}}$
will satisfy the equation $P(y^2)=0$. If this element is itself in the field 
$$\sqrt{\alpha + \beta \sqrt[3]{7} + \gamma \sqrt[3]{7^2}}= u + v \sqrt[3]{7}+w\sqrt[3]{7^2}$$
then the polynomial $P(y^2)$ of degree $6$ factors into two polynomials of degree $3$ with rational coefficients : $P(y^2)=Q(y)\cdot Q(-y)$.

So now we know the cubic polynomial

$$y^3- 3  u y^2+(3u^2-21 v w)y-(u^3 + 7v^3 + 49 w^3- 21 u v w)$$
and we get $u,v,w$.

ADDED: Let's take an example: find the square root of $469+ 259\sqrt[3]{7}+ 106\sqrt[3]{7^2}$. So $\alpha = 469$, $\beta=259$, $\gamma=106$.

1. Set up the polynomial 
   $$P(x) = x^3−3\alpha x^2 +(3\alpha^2 −21\beta \gamma)X−(\alpha^3+7 \beta^3 +49 \gamma^3− 21\alpha \beta \gamma)=\\=x^3 - 1407 x^2 + 83349 x - 12744900$$
2. Produce the polynomial $$P(y^2)=y^6 - 1407 y^4 + 83349 y^2 - 12744900$$
3. Factor the polynomial $P(y^2)$
   $$y^6 - 1407 y^4 + 83349 y^2 - 12744900=\\=(y^3 - 21 y^2 - 483 y - 3570) (y^3 + 21 y^2 - 483 y + 3570)$$
4. Solve the system
   $$ 3u = 21 \\
   3 u^2 - 21 v w = - 483\\
   u^3 + 7 v^3 + 49 w^3 - 21 u v w =3570$$

Get $u=7$, $v=6$, $w=5$. ( if we solved for the other factor we would get $(-7,-6,-5)$ ).

Comment: Well, calling $\lambda=7^{1/3}$, the characteristic polynomial for $\alpha+\beta\lambda+\gamma\lambda^2$ is $P(X)=X^3 -3\alpha X^2+(3\alpha^2-21\beta\gamma)X -(\alpha^3+7\beta^3+49\gamma^3-21\alpha\beta\gamma)$.

Comment: @Lubin: Thanks! Makes the second step straightforward.

Comment: I'm sorry, but i fail to understand this. Could you please elaborate on your answer of how to obtain $u,v,w$, thank you!

Comment: @Valeria G: From the coefficient of $y^2$ get $u$, then from coefficient of $y$ get $v w$, and then from the free term get a sum of cubes. Should be an easy system for $v$, $w$.

Comment: Im still at a loss, sorry. If i plug in $\alpha + \beta\sqrt[3]{7} + \gamma\sqrt[3]{7^2}$ in $y^2$ i fail to see how to extract $u$.

Comment: $\alpha=469 , \beta=259, \gamma=106$ :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75243/discussion-between-valeria-g-and-orangeskid).

Comment: @orangeskid: It is completely clear now. An elegant solution, superb! Thank you!